# check number of contacts and bodies in the world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi:

I am running a simulation program which asks atlas to pick up an object multiple times (supposed to be as many as possible) But the simulation slows down when it is running (after about 100 loops). And even, gazebo died after 294 loops. During the simulation, I delete and re-spawn the object in each loop. I am wondering that the object was not really deleted. On the list shown on the left of the gui, the object did disappear when it is deleted. Another thing that can slow down the simulation is the number of contacts is increasing all the time. Is there a way to check how many bodies and contacts in the world? Is there a debug mode that I can turned on to check them without recompiling gazebo?

Thanks
Best wishes
Cherry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2196/check-number-of-contacts-and-bodies-in-the-world/) by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think we have fixed the spawn/delete problem in the `default_worldname` branch. This branch will be merged into default by the end of the week, and made available via nightly builds.

You can visually see contacts through the "view" menu in the gui.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on 2013-04-29**:
I just saw your reply. That's cool! thanks!